# Mocking with Nock, mock only a specific route with the same host

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, nock

I am using Nock ( https://github.com/node-nock/nock ) to mock an underly service called by an endpoint that I need to test in my application. In the implementation of the endpoint, I am calling this underly service multiple time like that :

- http://samehost/specificrsc1/
- http://samehost/specificrsc2/
- http://samehost/specificrsc3/
- ...

**I want to know if it's possible to only mock ONE of those**. Let's say this one : 
http://samehost/specificrsc2/

Currently i am not able to achieve that. Because I get an error like this :

```
'FetchError: request to http://samehost/specificrsc1/ failed, reason: 
 Nock: No match for request {\n  "method": "GET",\n  "url": 
"http://samehost/specificrsc1/",
```

Thats how i am mocking the underly service :

```
const mockUnderlyCall = nock('http://samehost');
mockUnderlyCall.get('/samehost/specificrsc1').reply(200, mockData)
```

I also try :

```
const mockUnderlyCall = nock('http://samehost/samehost/specificrsc1');
mockUnderlyCall.get('').reply(200, mockData)
```

Thank you !

Comment: @OP: I'm facing the same problem. Have you found a workaround?

Comment: @eol No, we had to mock all endpoint, but to simplify the task we used a framework called node-replay (https://github.com/assaf/node-replay) it allow you to record the response that come from your underly service. Maybe that can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know if it's possible to only mock ONE of those

Yes, use the `allowUnmocked` option.

```
const mockUnderlyCall = nock('http://samehost', {allowUnmocked: true});
```

Note, this is listed in the [documentation](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#allow-unmocked-requests-on-a-mocked-hostname) for nock.

Answer (score 1):

Nock allows you to separate the hostname from the individual routes/endpoints.  Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your question, you just specify your paths separately.

Nock documentation is here:
https://github.com/nock/nock?tab=readme-ov-file#specifying-path

Suggested Code:

```
 nock('http://samehost')
    .get('/pvi/api/specificrsc3/')
    .reply();
```