# Mocking with nock. Mock only one path from the same host

Tags: node.js, nock

I'm using nock.
 I'd like to know if I can mock only some calls to a host, depending on the path. I am using { allowUnmocked: true }, it doesn't help.

For example, I'd like to mock only ONE of these calls (the numbers are ids, so I don't know them all):

- http://blabla.com/account/123456
- http://blabla.com/account/999999

This question is similar to this one:
[Mocking with Nock, mock only a specific route with the same host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798860/mocking-with-nock-mock-only-a-specific-route-with-the-same-host/48351371#48351371)

Answer (score 1):

this is what I did. I wanted to mock all calls that HAVE 123456 in their path. So, if the path doesn't have it, I return X, and only get those that are not X (using a negative look ahead regex)

```
nock(`https://my-url.com`, {
  allowUnmocked: true,
})
.filteringPath((thePath) => {
const match = /123456/.test(thePath);
return match ? thePath : 'X';
  })
.persist()
// This handles all request but 'X' (returned by the filteringPath fn).
.get(/^(?!(?:X)$).*$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nock interceptors [only fire once](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#read-this---about-interceptors)

You could configure one with a catch-all path like, like this:

```
nock('http://blabla.com').get(/account/) // if any path has 'account' in it, somewhere
```

Once that interceptor is caught, the next call to that matching URL will not be caught by nock.

Or you could specify a specific ID, like

```
nock('http://blabla.com').get('/account/' + id)
```

Obviously only that ID will be intercepted, as other IDs will not match the pattern. You can make different mock replies for each one too.

Comment: thank you. I took this and made a change so the logic is in a different function. The documentation wasn't clear for me.